# Invoking a method from a RecyclerView obtained using reflection

Tags: java, android, reflection, android-recyclerview

I need to access the methods of a `RecyclerView` that is created using a third party library.
What I'm doing is to get hold of the `RecyclerView` View using the findViewById:

```
ViewGroup mainView = mainActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    if(feedView == null){
        Object okStreamRecyclerView =  mainView.findViewById(NEWSFEED_RECYCLER_ID);
        feedView = (okStreamRecyclerView.getClass().getSuperclass()).getSuperclass();
        scrollToTop(feedView);
    }
```

At this point `feedView.getSimpleName` results in `RecyclerView`. Then I'm trying to scroll this `RecyclerView` to the top using:

```
private void scrollToTop(Class feedView) {
        log("THE VIEW IS OF TYPE: "+feedView.getName()); // androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        try {
            Method method = feedView.getMethod("getLayoutManager");
            method.setAccessible(true);
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) method.invoke(feedView);
            layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
           log("NO SUCH METHOD EXCEPTION",e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            log("ILLEGAL ACCESS EXCEPTION",e);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            log("INVOCATION TARGET EXCEPTION",e);
        }
    }
```

but for some reason I get the error bellow:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Expected receiver of type androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView, but got java.lang.Class<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

How can I convert the Class to the expected `RecyclerView`? Is there any other way to get hold of this view ?

Comment: Cast `okStreamRecyclerView` to be a `RecyclerView` and call `getLayoutManager()`, and get rid of all the reflection stuff.

Comment: @CommonsWare that's the first thing I tried. But for some reason I got the exception that I can't cast to the `RecyclerView`. Even when okStream is extending a clas that extends `RecyclerView`. Could it be failing to cast because the project generating okstream is using **androidx** and I'm not ?

Comment: "Could it be failing to cast because the project generating okstream is using androidx and I'm not ?" -- yes, insofar as there are separate `RecyclerView` classes. Having a mix of the Support Library classes and AndroidX is a risky proposition in the first place, so I would recommend that you move your own code up to AndroidX if you are going to use this library. Alternatively, if you want to try to use it as is, make sure that the `RecyclerView` that you are casting to is `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I used the **Androidx** version but I still get `java.lang.ClassCastException: StreamRecyclerView cannot be cast to androidx.recyclerview.widget.g` (I don't get the end of the class name). It's for this reason that I turned to reflection. Any idea how to go around this ?

Comment: Is the library that you are using open source?

Comment: @CommonsWare Unfortunately not, that’s why I turned to reflection as it seemed the last option. I’m kind of close to pull it but this cast exception is on the way and I’m not sure why. Also I can’t explain why I can’t cast to a parent class. Non-sense to me.

Comment: @CommonsWare If YOU don't have a solution for this issue, I might just give up...

Comment: Your error comes by passing `feedView` into `invoke()` -- you should be passing `okStreamRecyclerView` (the object on which you are trying to call `getLayoutManager()`). I suspect you will wind up with some other crash though, as if the cast doesn't work because `okStreamRecyclerView` is not a `RecyclerView`, then the reflect should fail as well, unless `StreamRecyclerView` happens to have its own `getLayoutManager()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @CommonsWare hint I managed to invoke the `ScrollToPosition` method using reflection. Here is the working code in my specific case, it might be easier in some other scenario:

```
View okStreamRecyclerView = null;
            try {
                okStreamRecyclerView = mainView.findViewById(NEWSFEED_RECYCLER_ID);
                feedView = (okStreamRecyclerView.getClass().getSuperclass()).getSuperclass();
                Method method = feedView.getMethod("getLayoutManager");
                method.setAccessible(true);
                LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) method.invoke(okStreamRecyclerView);
                Class llm = layoutManager.getClass().getSuperclass();
                Method m2 = llm.getMethod("scrollToPositionWithOffset",int.class, int.class);
                m2.setAccessible(true);
                m2.invoke(layoutManager,0,0);
            } catch (ClassCastException e){
                log("AN EXECPTON OCCURED WHILE FETCHING VIEW",e);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```